# XPath: get a node's sibling's string content

Tags: xpath

Assume the following HTML DOM:

```
<table id="my_id">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Location:</th>
            <td>
                1600 Parkway Ave
                Los Angels
                California
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I get '1600 Parkway Ave Los Angels California' assuming there are a lot of `<tr>` in this table? I think I need to get the sibling of the `<th>` that contains `Location:`. I've been trying to do something like:

```
//*[@id="my_id"]//th[Text()='Location:']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the `th` predicate up to `tr`...

```
//*[@id="my_id"]//tr[th='Location:']/td/text()
```

Update based on comment `The "Location:" string actually has whitespace around it.`:

```
//*[@id="my_id"]//tr[normalize-space(th)='Location:']/td/text()
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean the `td` is a child of the `tr`? They are siblings in the DOM, though.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - yes, but that is exactly what your example shows. In your example, they are not siblings.

Comment: The <th> is a sibling of the <td>

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - Correct. `th` and `td` are siblings. They are also children of `tr`.

Comment: OK, I understand your XPath a bit better now. Is whitespace ignored in XPath? The "Location:" string actually has whitespace around it.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - You can use `normalize-space()` so that whitespace isn't an issue. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
//*[@id="my_id"]//th[text()='Location:']/../td/text()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10518546)

Comment: @LucaDetomi ? It is a working solution. If tested it.

Comment: It was flagged as "low quality" due to its length and content. A so short answer, generally it's posted as a comment. I invite you to provide more details and better clarify "why" this is a correct solution :-)

Comment: It is obvious. Everybody who has used a path before is aware that `..` addresses the parent level. Also there has been discussion with the guy who made the accepted answer. We agreed that his is nice, but me will work as well. (We deleted afterwards to keep things clean) If this has been auto flagged, that it is a false positive.

Comment: I only suggested you what SO guidelines said. Moderators will decide if your answer is complete enough....